# How to create smarter toggle animation using velocity

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, velocity.js

I am using velocity.js to deal with animations and its for the most part great. I have a basic demo on codepen that displays a simple toggle button, however the js to make it animate is seemingly very cumbersome.

Whats the best way to deal with toggling animation like that in my example?

```
var open = false;

$('.filter').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var el = $(this);

    if(!open){

        el.find('.filter__line:first').velocity({translateY: [0, -5]}, 200, function(){
            $(this).addClass('filter__line--thick').velocity({rotateZ: '45deg'}, 200);
        });

        el.find('.filter__line:last').velocity({translateY: [0, 5]}, 200, function(){
            $(this).addClass('filter__line--thick').velocity({rotateZ: '-45deg'}, 200);
        });

        open = true;

    } else {

        el.find('.filter__line:first').velocity({rotateZ: '0deg'}, 200, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('filter__line--thick').velocity({translateY: [-5, 0]}, 200);
        });

        el.find('.filter__line:last').velocity({rotateZ: '0deg'}, 200, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('filter__line--thick').velocity({translateY: [5, 0]}, 200);
        });

        open = false;
    }

});
```

http://codepen.io/matt3224/pen/zGgKwP?editors=011

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used Velocity for a long time and ran into those sort of problems a lot. I would highly suggest GSAP if you're doing any sort of complex animations. GSAP timelines allow you to easily play, pause, and reverse a series of animations and the syntax is nice and clean. You can find more info on the [GSAP website](http://greensock.com/timelinelite).

[**I made a quick demo using this technique on Codepen**](http://codepen.io/mwujek/pen/OyLJer).

Here's what the script looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var top = $('.part-1');
var mid = $('.part-2');
var btm = $('.part-3');

var tl = new TimelineMax().pause();
  tl.to(mid, 0.3, {x:100, opacity:0})
  .to(top, 0.3, {rotation:18, transformOrigin:"left top"},"second")
  .to(btm, 0.3, {rotation:-18, transformOrigin:"left bottom"},"second");

var active = false;

  $('h1').click(function(){
    if(!active){
      tl.play();
      active = true;
    } else {
      tl.reverse();
      active = false;
    } 
  }); // end of click

}); // end of ready
```